# How is it possible to store 'like records' in a text file?

Tags: php

Please come and help. I am having a database that will continue to receive like records from users liking a particular post which will be too much in future for example if I have a 200,000 records with 100,000 likes each across the total records of like will be 20000000000 in my database. I am thinking of storing this like record in a text file and retrieve the records to prevent double entry. How do I go about this?

Comment: Wow you are going to beat Facebook. BTW sqlite is works as file, I think.

Answer (score 0):

If you go with file, concurrent transactions may have to wait for other threads to release the file resource. Try using nosql (MongoDB or Cassandra).